# Google Cloud Platform - Enforce Multi Factor Authentication (MFA)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, multi-factor-authentication, google-2fa

What is the proper way to configure / enforce MFA, so that all of the admin accounts in my Google Cloud Platform are required to have MFA configured and enabled? I found some guidance about this topic, but that required logging in each and every admin and checking manually.

Comment: MFA, also called 2-step verification (2SV), requires users to verify their identity through something they know (such as a password) plus something they have (such as a physical key or access code). Which solution would you like to use for the implementation of the 2-step verification?

Comment: Hi Ismael. I would like the users to be required to do 2 Step verification by SMS or the Google Authenticator App.

Comment: Think I found the solution. Need to "enable cloud identity and create an organisation", then migrate the resources to the organisation, then enable a mfa enforcement policy.

Comment: @romanhüsler if any answer has solved or helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**To set up cloud identity:**

Choose between Cloud Identity Free or Cloud Identity Premium. [In this link](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/editions#7431902), you can compare both editions.

- Instructions for signing up for [Cloud Identity Free](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/set-up-cloud-identity-admin?hl=en#sign-up-for-cloud-identity-free)
- Instructions for signing up for [Cloud Identity Premium](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/set-up-cloud-identity-admin?hl=en#sign-up-for-cloud-identity-premium)

> *To create your Cloud Identity account and first admin user using the Setup Wizard:*
>
> - In the About you section, enter your first and last name in the Name    field.
> - In the Current email address you use for the work field, enter the    email you used to create your prototype project.
> - This email address will be used as a recovery address. It must be    different from the address you create below that you'll use as your
>   admin account for Cloud Identity.
> - In the About your business section, enter your company name in the    Business or organization name field.
> - In the Country/Region field, choose the appropriate country or region    from the pulldown list.
> - Click Next to set up your domain.
> - In the Your Cloud Identity Domain window, add the domain you've    already purchased for your company. You'll need to verify that you
>   own it by creating a specific CNAME record or uploading an html file.
> - In the Create your Cloud Identity account window, enter a username    and password. This account is your Cloud Identity administrator
>   account and must be different from the email address you entered in
>   step 2 above. As a best practice, we recommend that you enter a
>   username with the following format: admin@example.com.

More information about setting up Cloud Identity can be [found here](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/set-up-cloud-identity-admin?hl=en#migrate-projects-and-billing-accounts-and-set-permissions).

Multi Factor authentication (MFA) is an important tool in protecting corporate resources. MFA, also called 2-step verification (2SV), requires users to verify their identity through something they know (such as a password) plus something they have (such as a physical key or access code).

**To deploy a 2-step verification**

> **Step 1:** Notify users of 2-Step Verification deployment (required) Before deploying 2-Step Verification, communicate your company’s plans
> to your users, including:
>
> - What is 2-Step Verification and why your company is using it
> - Whether 2-Step Verification is optional or required
> - If required, give the date by which users must turn on 2-Step    Verification Which 2-Step Verification method is required or
>   recommended.
>
> **Step 2:** Set up basic 2-Step Verification (required) Next, let your users turn on 2-Step Verification. By default, users can turn on
> 2-Step Verification and use any verification method. (G Suite accounts
> created before December 2016 have 2-Step Verification turned off by
> default).
>
> **Step 3:** Enforce 2-Step Verification (optional) As an administrator, enforcing 2-step verification for your users is an
> optional step.
>
> Make sure users are enrolled in 2-Step Verification before turning on
> enforcement. Users who aren’t enrolled can't sign in to their
> accounts.

**Enforcement methods**

- Any—Users can set up any 2-Step Verification method.
- All except verification codes via text, phone call—Users can set up
  any 2-Step Verification method except using their phones to receive
  2-Step Verification verification codes.
- Only security key—Users must set up a security key.

More detailed instructions [in this link.](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9176657?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-a--step-verification-method-to-enforce%2Callow-users-to-turn-on--step-verification%2Ctell-your-users-to-enroll-in--step-verification%2Ctrack-users-enrollment)

*If you want to use Text message or phone call as your 2-step verification method, consider:*

> If you currently allow any 2-Step Verification method, you probably
> have users who verify only by text and voice call. To avoid locking
> out these users from their accounts:
>
> Before enforcement takes effect, tell users to start using another
> 2-Step Verification method. Also, inform them that 2-Step Verification
> verification codes won't be available on their phones after the
> enforcement date. Use the login_verification Login Audit activity
> event to track users who sign in using 2-Step Verification
> verification codes they receive by text message or voice call. If the
> login_challenge_method parameter has the value
> idv_preregistered_phone, the user authenticated with a text or voice
> verification code.

[In this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839), you will find a more detailed guide for the users to activate their 2-step verification method.