# Enforce MFA for Google Cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, multi-factor-authentication, google-2fa

For security enhancement, I'd like to enforce MFA for everyone trying to access our Google Cloud project(s).

Our project has third-party partners, some of which doesn't have a domain and is using gmail.com addresses for authentication.

I did saw a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427172/google-cloud-platform-enforce-multi-factor-authentication-mfa), but it did not clarify what will happen to the users that do not belong to the same organization as the GCP project.

AFAIK, enforcing MFA can be enabled in Cloud Identity, which is not a Google Cloud product but a subset of Google Workspace. And, for accounts with gmail.com, there's no way I'm able to access the Cloud Identity settings for gmail.com.

In AWS IAM, we can use `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` in IAM policy condition for something similar to have conditional access for users with or without MFA.

Is there any way to reject Google API request from user has permission but without MFA enabled?

Comment: Your question sounds weird: MFA stands for Multi Factor Authentication, and you want to bind this with permission access. Sounds awkward! In any case, you could do nothing if the user account are not in your organization. In mine, even for partner, we create email in @ext.<mydomain> for external user and put them in a specific group. You wan't have the capacity to change the authentication method of third party gmail account (except if you buy Google!)

Comment: If possible, I don't want to create Google account for partners. Imagine having to log into 10 different Google account for every organization everyday. It's just too much pain even with a secure password manager.

The point of this question is to enforce MFA to whoever want to access the GCP project.

But it seems that GCP IAM has no idea if a user account has MFA enabled or not. I suppose the only solution, as you've said, is to create Google account in Cloud Identity, which I'm not the administrator of.

Comment: You can't grant access to Google Cloud to users in Cloud Identity. It's not a viable solution.